# Does Gradle use Ivy internally?

Tags: build, gradle, ivy

While trying to gather initial information on Gradle, I read this article:

http://techblog.chegg.com/2011/04/29/gradle-a-better-way-to-build/

It claims

> "internally, Gradle uses Ivy to manage dependencies"

Is this correct?

I thought Ivy, Maven and Gradle are completely different dependency management tools.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was correct in 2011, but isn't correct anymore. Today, Gradle comes with a full-fledged dependency management implementation that no longer builds upon Ivy, except for some traces that haven't been removed yet for backwards compatibility reasons. Nevertheless, Gradle continues to support Ivy and Maven repositories.